# Unable to read data from S4-System with App in Cloud Foundry via OData services

Tags: scp, s4sdk

When trying to call the OData service (in our example the BusinessPartnerService) on the S4 instances we have we are getting the error as seen in ref6 and ref7. However, if we are calling the API via a browser with the same credentials we can retrieve data from the system.
We want to understand what is causing the error and how to configure the connection in the cloud foundry environment correctly.
The full configuration of the system can be discussed and shown during a web session.

Comment: Pls post the error message.

Comment: "Unable to fecht the metadata: Failed to execute OData Metadata request.

Comment: SAP requested to Setup higher Log-Level on the S/4HANA System.

Comment: To wich Level should the Log-Level be changed?

Comment: Pls post the entire stack trace of the ODataException.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Pls provide more background of the issue and how you solved it, so that others can benefit it from it as well :)

Comment: Hello Andreas, posting an answer explaining your solution would be highly appreciated, as this question might be found by other people looking for help, and a "nevermind, fixed" post is not helpful in such cases. Thank you in advance.